# Geoserver 2.3.1 not finding all columns from PostGIS connection

Tags: postgis, geoserver

so I am not sure if I have missed something or this a particular problem with this version of Geoserver. I want to style a point layer with a SLD, based on values in a particular column. The column is an enumerated type relating to a type of activity.

i.e. type_of_activity: { camping, fishing, hunting }

But when I reach the configuration part of publishing the layer the column I base my style on is not present in the feature type details, and when previewing the layer, an exception is caused stating that "type_of_activity" does not exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It can't work because arrays and I supposed the more complex enumerated type seems to be not supported according to [this discussion](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/PostgreSQL-Arrays-td3794112.html) on Geoserver Users list

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be the case but I have been looking into extending [geoserver with geoscript](http://www.slideshare.net/jdeolive/scripting-geoserver-with-geoscript) and it seems there might be a way. I haven't had much time to look into it and there doesn't seem to be much documentation yet..

Comment: Coming back to this - following Andrea Aime's really useful talk at FOSS4G13 in Nottingham : )

By enabling the CSS extension then adding a column to the table containing a path to a specific symbol based on the enumerated type - it is possible to use the symbol column to style the individual features.